# Route values from HTTPContext in Webform

Tags: asp.net, webforms, routes

I'm using Routing in web-forms, I'm trying to write HTTP module in which I want to retrieve Route values from the route. When I try to use below line I get null. Is there anything other than this to get route data in web-forms? I want to know if the route that is currently in request context contains any route values in the route or not.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData
```

PS: I read in other posts on stack overflow that the above line works in MVC.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should take another look at your global.asax file and see if your route has actually been mapped properly or not.

Example

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}

public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute("",
        "Category/{action}/{categoryName}",
        "~/categoriespage.aspx");
}
```

For more details, please refer to the following links:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd329551.aspx#Anchor_1

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx#Anchor_2

Comment: the routes are registered properly and I'm able to reach pages using routes. but when i intercept the link using http module and try to read route values its giving me nothing.

Comment: Agree, I have just recently needed to retrieve some route data in static context and what OP is using gives me the information